# Unity won't integrate itself into Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity but one day after upgrading the Unity Editor to 2022.3.14f1
I get this error

Error while starting Visual Studio: ApplicationName='C:\Users\Admin\Test\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22\Editor\COMIntegration\Release\COMIntegration.exe', CommandLine='"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "C:\Users\Admin\Test\Test.sln" "C:\Users\Admin\Test\Assets\NewBehaviourScript.cs" -1', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.VisualStudioForWindowsInstallation:Open (string,int,int,string) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22/Editor/VisualStudioForWindowsInstallation.cs:329)
Microsoft.Unity.VisualStudio.Editor.VisualStudioEditor:OpenProject (string,int,int) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22/Editor/VisualStudioEditor.cs:232)
Unity.CodeEditor.CodeEditor:OpenProject (string,int,int)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

I've tried many ways, including ones listed by Unity. But no use

Comment: do you still have vs 2019? or did you upgrade to 2022?

Answer (score 0):

In Edit/Preferenes/External tools, find "External script editor" (it's on the top) and select another visual studio install from the list, or try to find it manually.